# can't start netperfmeter passive mode, kernel does not provide DCCP support, Debian 10

Tags: debian

Show the problem

```
# cat /etc/debian_version            
10.2
# 
# uname -a
Linux <redacted> 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
# 
# dpkg -l | grep netperfmeter
ii  netperfmeter                                                1.2.3-1+b1                           amd64        Network Performance Meter
# 
# netperfmeter 9000
Network Performance Meter - Version 1.0
---------------------------------------

Global Parameters:
   - Runtime           = until manual stop
   - Active Node Name  = Client
   - Passive Node Name = Server
   - Local Address(es) = (any)
   - Logging Verbosity = 9

NOTE: Compiled with MPTCP support, but unable to initialize it: Operation not permitted!
NOTE: Your kernel does not provide DCCP support.
ERROR: Failed to configure DCCP service code on DCCP socket (DCCP_SOCKOPT_SERVIC
E option) - Bad file descriptor!
#
```

I don't really want or need DCCP for `netperf`.

Questions

1. How can I start `netperfmeter` (passive) without DCCP?
2. How can I enable DCCP support in my kernel?

Answer (score 1):

The netperfmeter maintainer advised that this is a very old version of netperfmeter. This specific bug has already been resolved. https://github.com/dreibh/netperfmeter/issues/2

Debian needs to update the netperfmeter package to a more recent version. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=950271

I'm going to use UbuntuLTS and netperf; which is a more current version. https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/netperf

Answer (score 0):

To enable DCCP support, you can try

```bsh
sudo modprobe dccp
```

Comment: thank you @Pascal, but it doesn't resolve the previous error